Godot C# : Signals, delegates and events
I don't know if it's a Godot limitation...
I'm trying to declare some events in my C# file.
When you write "[Signal]" before a delegate declaration in Godot, the engine declares the correspondent event internally. Then you may use its "connect" ability, which substitutes the standard "EventName += Method;"
Unfortunately, it only works if "[Signal] delegate..." is declared inside of a public partial class, which is used in Godot node system. But, if I do, the interface would not contain the events declarations.
Is there any way to use the interface and [Signal] at the same  time in this context?
using Godot;

namespace Game.Component {
  public delegate void CurrentLifeChangedEventHandler(GodotObject sender, int amount); 
  public delegate void MaximumLifeChangedEventHandler(GodotObject sender, int amount); 
  public delegate void ExtraLifeChangedEventHandler(GodotObject sender, int amount); 
  public delegate void CurrentLifeReachedZeroEventHandler(GodotObject sender); 
  public delegate void MaximumLifeReachedZeroEventHandler(GodotObject sender); 
  public delegate void ExtraLifeReachedZeroEventHandler(GodotObject sender); 
  
  public interface ILifeComponent {
    event CurrentLifeChangedEventHandler CurrentLifeChanged; 
    event MaximumLifeChangedEventHandler MaximumLifeChanged; 
    event ExtraLifeChangedEventHandler ExtraLifeChanged; 
    event CurrentLifeReachedZeroEventHandler CurrentLifeReachedZero; 
    event MaximumLifeReachedZeroEventHandler MaximumLifeReachedZero; 
    event ExtraLifeReachedZeroEventHandler ExtraLifeReachedZero; 

    void InitializeHealth();
    void IncreaseMaximumLife(int amount);
    void IncreaseExtraLife(int amount);
    void TakeDamage(IDamage damage);  
    void HealLife(IHeal heal);
  }

  public partial class LifeComponent : Node, ILifeComponent{
    public event CurrentLifeChangedEventHandler CurrentLifeChanged; 
    public event MaximumLifeChangedEventHandler MaximumLifeChanged; 
    public event ExtraLifeChangedEventHandler ExtraLifeChanged; 
    public event CurrentLifeReachedZeroEventHandler CurrentLifeReachedZero; 
    public event MaximumLifeReachedZeroEventHandler MaximumLifeReachedZero; 
    public event ExtraLifeReachedZeroEventHandler ExtraLifeReachedZero; 


using Godot;
using Godot.Collections;

namespace Game.Component {

  public partial class ResistanceVulnerabilityComponent : Node, IResistanceVulnerabilityComponent {
    [Signal] public delegate void GainedResistanceEventHandler();
    [Signal] public delegate void GainedVulnerabilityEventHandler();
    [Signal] public delegate void LostResistanceEventHandler();
    [Signal] public delegate void LostVulnerabilityEventHandler();


Using C# Events
Using Godot Signals
It is kinda weird that we have to use "public partial class" in godot nodes.

If you want to pull event to the interface I think you can do something like this:
using Godot;
using Godot.Collections;
    
namespace Game.Component {
public interface IResistanceVulnerabilityComponent
{
    event ResistanceVulnerabilityComponent.GainedResistanceEventHandler GainedResistance;
}

public partial class ResistanceVulnerabilityComponent : Node, IResistanceVulnerabilityComponent {
    public event GainedResistanceEventHandler GainedResistance;
    [Signal]
    public delegate void GainedResistanceEventHandler();
}
}

